# Inserting Gridview Column from code behind based on random index in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to insert column into gridview, I have dropdown below the grid and dropdown is having 10 items now If i select random item assume that I am selecting 8 number item and add clicking add button. this item should create as new column at 8 number in grid.

Suppose grid is not having any column when page is loading and trying to insert column using below code throwing error.

var boundField = new TemplateField { HeaderText = "SelectedProductName"};
 grd.Columns.Insert(ddlProduct.SelectedIndex, boundField);

As Selected index can be any random number but grd is throwing out of index error as grid does not have that position.

Could you please help me to insert new column based on selected index from the dropdown.

My goal to achieve to display grid columns as they are listing into the dropdown same sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I defined a new class that will help us to store the columname and the index of that column in the dropdownlist:

```
public MyColumnClass
{

     public MyColumnClass();

     public int DDLindex {get;set;}
     public string ColumnName{get;set;}
}
```

Here is the main code, each time a new column added, the following code will re-order them, based on their order in the dropdownlist:

```
 BoundField boundField = new BoundField();
 boundField.DataField = drp_Items.SelectedItem.Text;
 boundField.Headertext = "Item";

 myGridView.Columns.Insert(0, boundField);

 //this list will store the existing 
 List<MyColumnClass> columnList = new List<MyColumnClass>();

 for(int x = 0; x < myGridView.Columns.Count; x++)
 {
      //dropdownlist index of the column
      var a = drp_Items.Items.IndexOf(drp_Items.Items.FindByValue(myGridView.Columns[x].DataField)); 
      MyColumnClass column = new MyColumnClass();
      column.DDLindex = a;
      column.ColumnName= myGridView.Columns[x].DataField;

      columnList.Add(column);
 }

 /the column list is created above, now we can clear the existing columns, and regenerate with the correct order
 myGridView.Columns.Clear();
 foreach(MyColumnClass item in columnList.OrderBy(c => c.DDLindex))//we order the list based on DDLindex
 {
      BoundField boundField = new BoundField();
      boundField.DataField = item.ColumnName;
      boundField.Headertext = "Item";

      myGridView.Columns.Add(boundField);

 }
```

P.S. You should make `autogeneratecolumns="false"` if you are binding data to Gridview.

Comment: Thank you.. But this will not solve my problem. I already tried this and it was getting add into the grid sequencially not to a particular order which i mention in the question. I need to create new column based on dropdown selected index and column index should be same.

For example.  Dropdown Items are
A
B
C

Now if i select C first grid should display C column as first place but if i select A after that Grid should display A first and C second. now if i select B that means now It should re-arrange with new column and should display A B C.

Comment: @user2720652 see my code again, I hope it will work :) it took really good amount of time :) if it does not work I will kill myself!